# Erlang Function call with default values and or without specific order

Tags: function, clojure, erlang, default-arguments

I'm new to Erlang and trying to find out the best way have defaults values for a function call, which requires several variables and / or also don't want to enter the arguments in a specific order. I'm currently using this format based loosely around Clojure's way. Is there a better way or method to achieve this in Erlang? I've also included a Clojure example as reference:

Erlang Version:

```
some_function_with_defaults() ->
    some_function_with_defaults(#{}).

some_function_with_defaults(Map) ->
    Defaults = #{
                arg1 => 0, % arg1 default value
                arg2 => 1, % arg2 default value
                arg3 => 2  % arg3 default value
              },

  Arguments = maps:merge(Defaults,Map),

  #{arg1 := Arg1} = Arguments,
  #{arg2 := Arg2} = Arguments,
  #{arg3 := Arg3} = Arguments,

  %% Do something with arguments
  [Arg1,Arg2,Arg3].

%% Example call using only defaults
%% some_function_with_defaults().
%%
%% [0,1,2]

%% Example call specifying a specific value
%% some_function_with_defaults(#{arg1 => 99}).
%%
%% [99,1,2]
```

Clojure Reference:

```
(defn some-function-with-defaults 
    [
     & {:keys
        [
         arg1
         arg2
         arg3

        ]
        :or
        {
         arg1 0 ;; arg1_default_value
         arg2 1 ;; arg2_default_value
         arg3 2 ;; arg3_default_value
        }
       }
  ]

  ;; Do something with arguments
  [arg1,arg2,arg3]
)

;; Example call using only defaults
;; (some-function-with-defaults)
;; 
;; [0,1,2]

;; Example call specifying a specific value
;; (some-function-with-defaults :arg1 99)
;;
;; [99,1,2]
```

Comment: Erlang is not Clojure, Python or anything even remotely close. The reason there is not a built-in facility for this in Erlang is because it doesn't make any sense to do so (there is literally no advantage, and rather a lot of disadvantage). If you want to write Clojure, write Clojure. Don't try to write Clojure in Erlang, you're only going to push yourself into impossibly weird places this way. What use is Dialyzer now, for example? What can you know about the *shape* of your data now? etc.

Comment: Respectfully, I'm not advocating one language over the other. It's a simple reference example, which could have been in any language. But I'm having to convert code project from Clojure to Erlang in this specific case. (real world)... I've seen Erlang records used in a similar manner (passed to functions) where records allow default values would that be a better approach? Since you're against this method. Again, I'm not trying to sell anyone on this method, but the existing code base is based on it. What is the best way to handle default values to functions in Erlang?? Just looking for advice.

Comment: Record default values are one approach, even better is an opaque type that you abstract somewhere else. With an opaque type you don't care if the data is in a map, a record, a dict, or whatever -- and with an opaque type you can still provide a typing guarantee along with defaults or whatever you want. The key here is to realize that there is a difference between providing defaults within a *data structure* and default *arguments*. They are not the same thing. Erlang is functional, and to wield it properly you have to embrace the semantics of actual functions (as opposed to procedures).

Comment: Another approach is to pass a proplist as single parameter to function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the approaches I often seen before maps arrived is to have:

- proplist with optional arguments
- record with default values
- function witch take values from proplist and put it into a record.

```erlang
-record(options, {
    opt_int = 42     :: integer(),      % default is 42
    opt_bool = false :: boolean(),      % default false
    opt_atom         :: undefined | val % default undefined
}).
parse_opts(Opts) ->
    parse_opts(Opts, #options{}).

parse_opts([], Res) ->
    Res;
parse_opts([{opt_int, Val} | RestOpts], Res) when is_integer(Val) ->
    parse_opts(RestOpts, Res#options{opt_int = Val});
parse_opts([{opt_bool, Val} | RestOpts], Res) when is_boolean(Val) ->
    parse_opts(RestOpts, Res#options{opt_bool = Val});
parse_opts([{opt_atom, Val} | RestOpts], Res) when Val == undefined; Val == val ->
    parse_opts(RestOpts, Res#options{opt_atom = Val}).
```

`parse_opts([{opt_int, 55}])` will give you `#options{opt_int = 55, opt_bool = false, opt_atom = undefined}`

This is little bit awkward, mainly because records is compile-time syntax sugar over tuples. You can do more elegant thing with maps though.

P.S. didn't test this, so may contain few errors.

P.P.S. It will throw exception if you pass unknown option.

Comment: +1: Proplists are the conventional way to do this, often with a convert-to-record function like the one here.